# How to instantiate a pushbutton from ui into the code in QT framework

Tags: c++, qt

What I intent to do is just a basic animation in my qt application. For the animation, when the button is clicked, I want it to go from one point to another in a time interval. Here is my code (main.cpp and mainWindow.h are the same as default. ):

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pButton_clicked()
{
    QPushButton* pb = ui->pButton;
    QPropertyAnimation anim(pb, "geometry");
    anim.setStartValue(QRect(100,100,100,30));
    anim.setEndValue(QRect(900,900,100,30));
    anim.setDuration(10000);
    anim.start();
}
```

Build works with no errors. The problem is, when I click the button, its position properties just transforms to the startvalues but stays there instead of moving to the endpoint. Why it remains stationary?

And, lastly, my other question is how can I get a reference of a widget that I created on ui design. I know one way which I used in my code, getting the button using `ui->pButton`. But in this way I must create the `QPushButton` variable as a pointer. Is there any way I can reference a button into code which was added to ui using  ui designer (not using code to generate).

Comment: Your `QPropertyAnimation` instance `anim` is local to `MainWindow::on_pButton_clicked` and will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.  Hence the animation never starts.  Try making `anim` a class member or allocate it on the heap and start it with the deletion policy `QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped`.

Comment: I recommend you should split your questions.
As for the last point: `QPushButton& pb = *ui->pButton` won't work?

Comment: The problem is I cannot use ui->pButton anywhere but the " ui->setupUi(this); " part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the `anim` object as local variable. As soon as `on_pButton_clicked()` function exits, `anim` variable will get destroyed. Create `anim` object on the heap, as shown below, then your code should work fine.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pButton_clicked()
{
    QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pButton, "geometry");
    anim->setEndValue(QRect(900,900,100,30));
    anim->setEndValue(QRect(500,500,100,30));
    anim->setDuration(10000);
    anim->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

[image]

Comment: this time it gives excess elements in scalar initializer

Comment: What do you mean? Are you getting error message?

Comment: I tested it on Qt 5.12.3 on Windows, and it works fine. Let us know, in detail, what is the issue.

Comment: sorry couldnt edit the comment. Yep when I did in the way you did, it gave me excess in scalar initializer error. I am using 5.12.2. To be honest with you, I roughly know about stack and heap concepts, but the point where I get confused is, where should I write the code.  When I tried to do it outside of  any mainwindow:: function, it gives "unknown type ui".

Comment: You should add this code in the slot of pushButton, I've updated my answer to include the complete function. If you still face any issue, please share your updated code, so that we can have a look.

Comment: Went through your answer again, now it works, that is brilliant. So now creating anim object as pointer, did we create that on the "heap"?

Comment: Yes, whenever you use `new` operator to allocate memory, it gets allocated on the heap.